# Function that fills in missing numbers to create complete sequence

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function that will fill in any missing numbers in between two numbers in a list. The original list must be altered and cannot be new.

For example: [13,15,20] would return [13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20].

Note that I am not allowed to use a range function.

Here's my code:

```
def complete(list1):
    i= 0
    if len(list1) > 1:
        for number in list1:
           if number - list1[i+1] != -1:
               number += 1
               list1.insert(i + 1, number)
           i += 1
        return list1
    else:
        return list1
```

I got a "list index out of range" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source of your error:

```
...
for number in list1:
    if number - list1[i+1] != -1:
        ...
    i += 1
```

Basically, there comes a point (that point being the last `number` in `list1`) when `i+1` gets you out of bounds and you are not doing anything to prevent that from happening. Indexing is tricky like that, so I would like to offer an indexing-free (well, almost) approach. By the way, from your comment to Bonfire's answer, I see that the task is to change original lists in-place. While mutating arguments is considered a very poor coding practice these days, here is a relatively efficient way of doing that:

```
import typing as t

def complete_sequence(partial: t.List[int]) -> t.List[int]:
    # edge case
    if len(partial) < 2:
        return partial
    # a lookup table for numbers we already have
    observed = set(partial)
    # append numbers we don't have
    start = partial[0]
    stop = partial[-1]
    num = start + 1
    while num < stop:
        if not num in observed:
            partial.append(num)
        num += 1
    # in-place sort
    partial.sort()
    return partial
```

As you see, instead of inserting values between existing numbers (paying O(n) time for each insertion), we can simply append everything (O(1) per insertion) and sort. This not only simplifies the logic (we no longer have to track those pesky indices), but also reduces computational time-complexity from O(n^2) to O(n*log(n)).

Comment: Hi, truly appreciate your input. However, since this is a question intended for total python beginners, I think that your code might be too advanced.

Comment: @ccxy This answer is the answer you should be studying as a beginner.

Comment: Well noted! Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @ccxy I beg to differ with your opinion on what solution is more or less advanced. From my point of view, complicated indexing logic requires a lot more skill than the rather straightforward approach in my answer.

Comment: Hi Eli, I received feedback from my tutor for both codes(I simplified Bonfire's codes) and while your codes are better due to its straightforwardness, my tutor encouraged me to use indexing logic for this case just to give us a better understanding of how it works, and also partially due to the fact that we haven't touched on import concepts, set() and sort() functions at the moment. For the future benefit of the SO community, I have green-ticked your answer which has a simpler approach. Once again thank you so much for your ideas! :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want to do I have made some changes to the logic:

```py
def complete(list1):
    if len(list1) < 2 : return list1

    num = list1[0]
    i = -1

    while num < list1[-1]:
        num += 1
        i += 1

        if num in list1: continue

        if i < len(list1) - 1:
            list1.insert(i + 1, num)
        else:
            list1.append(num)

    return list1

print(complete([13, 14, 20]))
#  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

print(complete([13, 14, 15]))
#  [13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that the original list must be altered and cannot be new. I have edited the question.

Comment: I will see what I can do then.

Comment: Hi Bonfire, I changed the green-tick to Eli's answer just to provide a more straightforward alternative for the SO community for future reference. To clarify, this act is in no way disapproving your answer, in fact, your answer has been of great help and I have used your index logic ideas to further improvise my codes. I hope you understand my reasons and thank you very much for your ideas! :)  -sincerely ccxy-

Comment: I understand your reasons and I don't have any problems with that. No need to apologize!